Encapsulating requestAnimationFrame loop in a class loses the object's this reference
I would like to roll a JavaScript class for doing animations via window.requestAnimationFrame. Unfortunately, when I run my code, the Google Chrome Developer Tools throws this at me:
script.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '#counter')
    at #loop (script.js:10:47)

Superficially, it seems like that after the first iteration the reference this is lost. How could I circumvent that issue?
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebTest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            const alerter = new Alerter();
            alerter.start();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

script.js:
class Alerter {
    
    #counter = 0;
    
    start() {
        this.#loop();
    }
    
    #loop() {
        const yes = confirm("Counter " + this.#counter + ". Continue?");
        
        if (!yes) {
            return;
        }
        
        this.#counter++;
        
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.#loop);
    }
}


Does this answer your question? How to access the correct `this` inside a callback

window.requestAnimationFrame((ms) => this.#loop(ms)); (I included the function parameter in case you'll need it in the future)

ouch!!! why would you use a confirm in a RequestAnimationFrame callback!!!

@JaromandaX Only for controlling the demo.

@JaromandaX Sir, you are amazing! Thanks! You just saved me many hours worth effort.

As the comments say you can fix it by wrapping the callback in an arrow function.
class Alerter {
    
    #counter = 0;
    
    start() {
        this.#loop();
    }
    
    #loop() {
        console.log("Counter " + this.#counter);
        this.#counter++;
        window.requestAnimationFrame((ms) => this.#loop(ms));
    }
}

let a = new Alerter()
a.start()

